# Linking to a specific part of a page - Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I have a route that is built which properly appends `#fans` at the end of the link...

`http://localhost:3000/.../community#fans`

I also have `id` set for `fans` in the below code (third line)

1) Even though the link is properly filled when a button is clicked (the address in the address bar is the address as shown above), it does not actually go to the part of the page with id `fans`.

2) But if I go to `http://localhost:3000/.../community` first and then type `#fans` at the end of the link, that works. If i remove the `id`, `#fans` does not work so I think the code below is fine.

Given #2, I don't understand why #1 is an issue especially since the link that works is the same link that gets generated for the button. Is there a reason why it would work when manually entering the id tag but not when generated?

```
<panelWithTopTitleAndOptionalTopButton 
    class="panelWithCards our-fans" 
    id="fans"
    :class="{ hasNoCards: !fans || !fans.length }" 
    :name="fansTitle" 
    v-if="!!fansTitle">

    <transition-group name="list" tag="div">
        <memberCard class="card fan"
            v-for="fan in fans"
            v-if="!!fan"
            :card="fan"
            @delete-member="onDeleteMemberPosition"
            type="fans"
            :key="fan.key" />
    </transition-group>
    <div 
        v-if="showLoadMoreButton" 
        class="load-more" 
        @click="loadMore"
    >LOAD MORE</div>
</panelWithTopTitleAndOptionalTopButton>
```

Comment: Do you use `vue-router` for routing? If so, what mode do you use: history or hash?

Comment: Could you give us the `loadMore` function ?

Comment: @vahdet - It looks there isn't explicit configuration being done for the router which means its "hash".  Given the documentation, it sounds like it should work?

Comment: To be clear, yes vue-router is being used but not configured anywhere so the site is using the default option